# Installing RVM, Ruby on Debian 7 getting error user is not allowed to execute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, debian, rvm

I installed RVM as regular user (non-root) but when it comes to install Ruby

```
rvm install ruby
```

I got this error:

```
xsma@ACS:~$ rvm install ruby
Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
Found remote file https://rvm.io/binaries/debian/7/i386/ruby-2.1.1.tar.bz2
Checking requirements for debian.
Installing requirements for debian.
Updating systemxsma password required for 'apt-get --quiet --yes update': 
xsma password required for 'apt-get --quiet --yes update': 
....
Error running 'requirements_debian_update_system ruby-2.1.1',
showing last 15 lines of /home/xsma/.rvm/log/1397842665_ruby-2.1.1/update_system.log
++ missing_paths+=:/usr/sbin
++ for sbin_path in /sbin /usr/sbin /usr/local/sbin
++ [[ -d /usr/local/sbin ]]
++ [[ ! :/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games:/home/xsma/.rvm/bin: =~ :/usr/local/sbin: ]]
++ missing_paths+=:/usr/local/sbin
++ [[ -n :/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/sbin ]]
++ command_to_run=(/usr/bin/env PATH="${PATH}${missing_paths}" "${command_to_run[@]}")
++ command_to_run=(${sudo_path}sudo -p "%p password required for '$*': " "${command_to_run[@]}")
++ sudo -p '%p password required for '\''apt-get --quiet --yes update'\'': ' /usr/bin/env PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games:/home/xsma/.rvm/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/sbin apt-get --quiet --yes update
Sorry, try again.
Sorry, user xsma is not allowed to execute '/usr/bin/env PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games:/home/xsma/.rvm/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/sbin apt-get --quiet --yes update' as root on ACS.ACS.
++ return 1
++ typeset __ret=1
++ case ${__ret} in
++ return 1
Requirements installation failed with status: 1.
xsma@ACS:~$
```

before it was saying "xsma is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be reported.
" and i solved it by adding xsmas in the sudoers file like this: "xsma  ALL=(All:ALL) ALL" but it still comes out with another error: "Sorry, user xsma is not allowed to execute..."
And i don't know how figure it out. please help!

Here is  /etc/sudouers file:

```
#
# This file MUST be edited with the 'visudo' command as root.
#
# Please consider adding local content in /etc/sudoers.d/ instead of
# directly modifying this file.
#
# See the man page for details on how to write a sudoers file.
#
Defaults    env_reset
Defaults    mail_badpass
Defaults    secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"

# Host alias specification

# User alias specification

# Cmnd alias specification

# User privilege specification
root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
xsma ALL=(All:ALL) ALL

# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# See sudoers(5) for more information on "#include" directives:

#includedir /etc/sudoers.d
```

when i execute groups i got only  root

Comment: well, for debian just try firstly: `sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`. then `rvm requirements`, then `rvm install ruby-2.1.1`

Comment: i did  "sudo apt-get update" and "sudo apt-get update" but nothing new. And when i execute "rvm requirements" it asks me for the password, i enter the password and the same error occurs with this line: "Sorry, user xsma is not allowed to execute..."

Comment: so you can run `sudo apt-get update` successfully?

Comment: yes from root not with "xsma" user. When i do it with xsma it shows this error: "Sorry, user xsma is not allowed to execute '/usr/bin/apt-get update' as root on ACS.ACS.
"

Comment: please show your `/etc/sudoers`, and output of `groups`

Comment: i idited the post with what you asked.

Comment: change `root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL` to `root   ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL` and retry

Comment: not quite: secure is `root   ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/apt-get`

Comment: ok, i did it but it's still the same

Comment: like that ? root ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/apt-get /usr/bin/env

Comment: i don't know how to add both path, but it is not working with any of them

Comment: is not working with it `root   ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL`?

Comment: no  it doesn't work with that

Comment: ok, add the line `root   ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL` to sudoers, and update the run log with enabled set.

Comment: i added the line, but what dou you mean by "update the run log with enabled set" ?

Comment: I meant log with lines `++ missing_paths+=:/usr/sbin`... etc. as weel as you have done it already

Comment: Well, and provide output of `rvm -v`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i worked it  out by restarting. it seems that the system needed a restart in order to use the new config properly.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your user is not added to sudo correctly, try to write in sudoers like this:

#### xsma     ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

and check if it works with "sudo -i" in console

---

So there are several ways you can solve this problem:

1) make sudo for your user 
2) make aptitude update and aptitude upgrade with root rights (logged like root)

Try to read this, maybe this will help you to configure sudoers right https://wiki.debian.org/sudo

Comment: i did it, it didn't work. and sudo -i  gives this error: "Sorry, user xsma is not allowed to execute '/bin/bash' as root on ACS.ACS"

Comment: Try to read manual https://wiki.debian.org/sudo or http://www.debianhelp.co.uk/sudo.htm (more simple), if you will get same error it's mean that you doing something wrong (saving file without privileges and it's actually not saved, or you make some typo)